# Does Ballerina support Switch-case?

Tags: ballerina

I'm trying a use case where it is cleaner to use switch-case than if-else.
For each school Id, I want to mock the response JSON. I couldn't find it at [Ballerina-by-example](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/) section.

```
if ("34534253" == schoolId) {
    json flightDetails = {
        "schoolId": schoolId,
        "Name": "School ABC",
        "Address": "344 Scarbrough Ln, Cordova, TN 38018",
        "Principal": "John Due"
    };
}
```

Anyone knows is it going to add in the future or the reason if not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ballerina does not have the switch-case statement. The only option is to use the if/else at the moment. We are considering improving the match statement as follows.

```
match schoolId {
    "1234343" => ...
    "4538798" => ...
    "7766383" => ...
}
```

Comment: Match with guards, like it Rust would be a good addition and will be very powerful. https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/flow_control/match/guard.html